# what is the correct way to read from a datarow if the cell might be null

Tags: c#, null, datarow

I have the following code which seems to blow up if the column in the datarow (dr) is null.  what is the correct way to parse out the value from the data row and handle null checks?

```
Person person = new Person()
{
    FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString(),
    LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString(),
    BusinessPhoneNumber = dr["BusinessPhone"].ToString(),
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the column is of type string, but is nullable, what about trying:

```
// FirstName must allow null
FirstName = dr["FirstName"] as string
```

or

```
// FirstName would be empty for a NULL in the database
FirstName = (dr["FirstName"] as string) ?? string.Empty
```

Comment: Strings are "nullable" by default, since they are reference types.

Comment: I was talking about the column and not the string type.

Answer (score 5):

I believe, the data cell beeing null cannot be the reason for your problem. Maybe the column doesn't exist, or any other error happened, or the DataRow itself is null and you should handle that. Look at the exception - "seems to blow up" is not a valid description of your problem.

The following explains that, but will also answer the question from the title for everyone else.

If the column value is null, an object `System.DBNull` is returned, and `.ToString()` returns an empty string, while `(string)` or `as string` return `null`.

So it makes no sense to check the returned item for `==null` because that won't ever evaluate to `true`.

- If you accept empty strings as result, your code is already optimal, no need to handle the `DBNull` case.
- If you want to get `null`, change `.ToString()` to `as string`.
- If you want to handle it in any other way, use `if (dr.IsNull("FirstName"))` or do `==null` on the target variable after the `as string`.

Answer (score 2):

`dr["FirstName"].ToString()` will occasionally throw null pointer exceptions because you're trying to access `ToString` on a null object. Other than that, strings can be null, so really, if you know it's a string, and you don't mind that it's null, it'd be safe to do

```
FirstName = (String) dr["FirstName"]
```

Comment: That's wrong, null pointer exceptions won't happen here. If the column content is null, an object `System.DBNull` is returned, and `.ToString()` returns an empty string, while `(string)` or `as string` return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the column, and a default value to a helper function that checks for null and returns the default if null, or the column value if not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to return a blank string if the column is null.

```
FirstName = string.format("{0}", dr["FirstName"])
```